Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists
Ok, so I have a big problem, which I don't know how to solve. I tried with phin, chatgpt, the mariadb docs and docker docs. so my problem is, that I everytime get the error, which is discribed in the title.
So the thing is that I need to make a dockernetwork with wordpress, mariadb and nginx. nginx and wordpress are working perfectly but mariadb always have problem that a socket or something doesn't exist and the mariadb server cant start.
This is the errorlog. I tried it without host, with host "localhost", "127.0.0.1" and with the stated "mariadb". but everytime the same error
.env file not found!
MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=wordpress
MARIADB_DATABASE=wordpress
MARIADB_USER=wordpress
MARIADB_PASSWORD=wordpress
Create safe copy...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mariadb' (115)
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mariadb' (115)" when trying to connect
Starting MariaDB...
Path exists
File exists
Socket nicht gefunden. Erstelle ihn...
Waiting for MariaDB...
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'mariadb' failed
error: 'Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mariadb' (115)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
MariaDB not available. Waiting for 5 seconds...
240928 18:57:53 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
240928 18:57:53 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

This is my .sh file which runs the whole thing
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD" ] || [ -z "$MARIADB_DATABASE" ] || [ -z "$MARIADB_USER" ] || [ -z "$MARIADB_PASSWORD" ]; then
    echo "env variables missing!"
    exit 1
else
    if [ ! -f "/app/.env" ]; then
        echo ".env file not found!"
        mkdir app
        cd /app
        touch .env
        echo "MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD
MARIADB_DATABASE=$MARIADB_DATABASE
MARIADB_USER=$MARIADB_USER
MARIADB_PASSWORD=$MARIADB_PASSWORD" >> .env
        cd ..
        if [ ! -f "/app/.env" ]; then
            echo "ENV doesnt exist. exiting"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
fi

cat /app/.env
source /app/.env

echo "Create safe copy..."
mysqldump -u root -p$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD $MARIADB_DATABASE -h mariadb | mysql -u root -p$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD $MARIADB_DATABASE -h mariadb

echo "Starting MariaDB..."
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &

if [ ! -d "/var/run/mysqld" ]; then
    echo "Path doesnt exist"
else
    echo "Path exists"
fi

if [ ! -f "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock" ]; then
    echo "File exists"
else
    echo "File exists"
fi


if [ ! -f "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock" ]; then
    echo "Socket nicht gefunden. Erstelle ihn..."
    ln -sf /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
fi

echo "Waiting for MariaDB..."
until mysqladmin -u root -p$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD -h mariadb ping; do
  echo "MariaDB not available. Waiting for 5 seconds..."
  sleep 5
done

echo "Creating user and db..."
cat << EOF > /etc/mysql/init.sql
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $MARIADB_DATABASE;
    CREATE USER '$MARIADB_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$MARIADB_PASSWORD';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $MARIADB_DATABASE.* TO '$MARIADB_USER'@'%';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EOF
mysql -u root -h mariadb < /etc/mysql/init.sql

echo "Database and user successfully created."

# Halte den Container am Leben
# tail -f /dev/null

The host in wordpress config.php is mariadb. thats the command:
wp config create --dbname=$MARIADB_DATABASE --dbuser=$MARIADB_USER --dbpass=$MARIADB_PASSWORD --dbhost=mariadb --allow-root
I tried (as I said) to change the host in -h. also I tried without host. I tried without creating the socket and with creating the socket. I also tried to change the hostname in the wp-config.php

How do you use this bash script?  How are you launching the containers?  Is the error coming from this script, or one of the other containers you mention?  It looks like the script is trying to replicate the "create a database and a user" setup that the standard Docker Hub database images do on their own; can you just delete this script, and make sure an appropriate env_file: is set for the database in the Compose file?

so firtst of all I launch all the scripts with the CMD command in the dockerfile and all containers from the docker-compose.yml. the thing is I need a .sh file and a dockerfile, because the subject of my university states that I need to do it like that.
And yes, I try to create a database and a admin user with the script

Is the container actually running?  It looks like your script may get to the end trying to leave a background process running, and if that happens, the container will exit.  You should not need a custom Docker image here, the unmodified mariadb image should be able to create the initial user based on an environment variable setting in the Compose file.

The distro/packaging of MariaDB will determine its default socket location. Explicit handing not recommended as the configuration file and default client utilities will know where it is. Recommend omit trying to handle socket location - mariadb ping will handle it. If it doesn't MariaDB didn't start - show the logs. You university constraints are a bit mad - include them so we can move from obvious solution to "academic solutions". FLUSH PRIVILEGES not required after GRANT/CREATE USER - check the documentation. create user if not exists for consistency.

Containers need the mariadbd as the final process on PID once - hence exec. Take a look at the other nuggets of wisdom in the official images entrypoint
